# Get Json data(Object in Object) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, for-loop

I am using Laravel and Mongodb.

My JSON output:

```
[{"_id":"58aabc59836a0656da4e4c71",
"userid":"KT0001",
"username":"Ashok kumar",
"email":"ashok@ymail.com",
"mobileno":8015681377,
"manager_mail":"anandan@kxxxx.com",
"roleid":2,
"role":  {"_id":"58996226d31868ea68c7b52c",**"roleid":2,"rolename":"Admin"**}
},
]
```

I want to get the role id and role name, i can get the other details except `rolename`, i tried retrieving it with the following but no result.

```
for(i=0;i<userdata.length;i++)
         { 
            $('<option/>', {
              value: userdata[i].roleid,
              html: userdata[i][role].rolename
            }).appendTo('select#userrole');
         };
```

Please help?

Comment: change this: `userdata[i][role].rolename` by `userdata[i]['role'].rolename` and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like

```
 userdata[i].role.rolename
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
userdata[i][role].rolename
```

to this:

```
userdata[i]['role'].rolename
```

---

`'role'` key is a string and you are using it as a variable name.

Comment: you don't think so this little correction, you also suggest by comment ..!!

Comment: @SoniVimal what could be the answer in your opinion. This is where i found issue and it should work if it is.

Comment: Thank you all, both userdata[i].role.rolename and userdata[i]['role'].rolename working, what is the proper way?

Comment: both are absolutely valid but chosen one can create issues if one can try to minify the js.